# how can i reduce the size of complete row when screen size is 450px

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, media-queries

please tell me how to manage the size of the contents inside the row how to reduce size of these images and the text when size of the display is 450 img trying to to this with media query but i'm unable to understand how to do this please help me anyone.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <img src="img/anarf.gif" alt="anar">
  </div> <div class="col-sm-4 text-center">
  <img src="img/diya.gif" alt="diya" style="margin-top:100px;">
  <br>
  <span id="fname">From :-</span>
  <span id='fname'><?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?>
    </span>
  <br>
  <span id='fname'><?php echo $_POST["message"]; ?>
  </span> 
</div> 
  <div class="col-sm-4">
    <img src="img/girl.gif" alt="girl" style="margin-top:23px;">
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-4"><img src="img/anarf.gif" alt="anar"></div>
      <div class="col-sm-4 text-center"><img src="img/diya.gif" alt="diya" style="margin-top:100px;"><br>
         <span id="fname">From :-</span> <span id='fname'><?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?></span><br>
         <span id='fname'><?php echo $_POST["message"]; ?></span>
    </div>
         <div class="col-sm-4"><img src="img/girl.gif" alt="girl" style="margin-top:23px;"></div>       
  </div>

Comment: @Manish, I believe Dima Kozhevin meant for you to [edit] your post and include the code in there, rather than as a comment.

Comment: I have tried to do that many time but it show an error.